# ASP.NET MVC : how to display int rating value in star in a table?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have a database like:

[image: database]

I want to display the rating of the question.

The column `Rating` is int contain the rating point from each user.

How can I display this int value as a rating star?

Please help me - how do I start my controller and view?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using JQuery plugin , so you pass the value you want to the view as usual , the same way you pass all the model data , after that , The Jquery plugin is gonna take care of displaying that value in form of stars . all you have to do is including the Jquery plugin in your scripts and follow the documentation on how to use it. For that purpose , I advise you to use the RateYo plugin , you find [here](https://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/) all the required info about it and how to use it . For mopre options , you may refer to [this link](https://jqueryhouse.com/20-best-jquery-rating-plugins/) to choose a different plugin

Comment: The problem is not about a plugin to to use. He first have to find the average rating from 5 stars to 1 stars the return the average rating before a plugin will come in. Plugins just display the stars according to the value you pass to them

Comment: @Tavershima Yes , im self learning , have no idea on hwo t ofind the average and pass over

Comment: @ironman , I think finding the average out of a list of rates is a simple algorithmic matter , if you have a list of integers , can't you just get the average . once you do that , you may send it to the view in order to be diplayed in form of stars . IMHO , if you can't find the average out a list of integers , well maybe you will need to learn a little of basic algorithms before diving into web apps .

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add a new controller
2. Add a new View
3. Add a model to hold the value "Rating"
4. look into how to get your connection string and connect to your database
5. Initialise the model in your new controller
6. populate the model with the value from the database
7. return the model to the view

go step by step and research each bit